# C# MVC 5 : How to hash password

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, passwords

Someone can help me, i try to create AspNetUser (Table generate from mvc login, added somes attributes to this basic entity), i want to hash the passwork exactly in the same way like the function 
User.Create(user, passwordToHash)

```
var user = new AspNetUser();
user.UserName = "admin@mail.com";
user.Email = "admin@mail.com";
user.Nickname = "SuperAdmin"; // added by me
user.EmailConfirmed = true;
string userPWD = "PassToHash123";
user.PasswordHash = // Need Help 
db.AspNetUsers.Add(user);
db.SaveChanges();

// function to create standard user which not work with my modified AspNetUser
var chkUser = UserManager.Create(user, userPWD);
```

But, i dont know if a function exist ?

Can you tell me if, there is a function and if not, i need to change the system of login in the application ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

The UserManger has a property [PasswordHasher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/mt151662%28v%3Dvs.108%29). If available, use this one for creating your hash else implement and set your own PasswordHasher.

Answer (score -1):

You can use MD5 Algorithm to hash your string password to 36 chars long hash string.

```
public static string MD5Hash(string input)
{
   StringBuilder hash = new StringBuilder();
   MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
   byte[] bytes = md5provider.ComputeHash(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(input));

   for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
   {
     hash.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
   }
   return hash.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thx for your function, but your function is not hashing like the mvc userManager ?

Comment: Give me a sample hash string from UserManager.

Comment: Don't do this. MD5 is cracked.

Comment: You should use: 1. A secure hashing algorithm. 2. A slow hash (i.e. not just SHA256 etc...), but a scheme specifically for passwords. 3. You should use a random salt that is appended to the password and to the stored hash, so that the same password will not hash to the same value twice. 4. You should not try to write this code yourself - use a library.